# Evolution of Aye Yah?

Tags: word-usage

How did "aye yah" get its start in our language? For example, "Waste not, want not — aye yah."

Did it originate in the northeast or southern California? I've googled but cannot find a definitive answer regarding "aye yah."

Or when one says, "Christmas presents, aye yah." What does that mean? I heard it was a common utterance of forest rangers.

Your thoughts?

Comment: Were any of those forest rangers [Chinese](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ai%20ya)?

Comment: Has it gotten a start?

Comment: Nobody ever says it where I live.